# Is there a way to change all the shortcuts in IntelliJ Idea (Mac) to be the same as under Linux?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have recently been handed a company laptop that runs on MacOS. I've been using Linux for 20 years now. The MacOS shortcuts are literally driving me insane and I am looking for a way to have the same ones as under Linux. Is there a way to so this? Perhaps by replacing the shortcuts mapping file, or something?

Please, advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download keymaps as a plugin from the plugin repository. Go to `Preferences | Plugins` and search for "keymap" in the Marketplace. This will show you a list of all the keymap plugins that are available. You probably need either "GNOME Keymap" or "KDE Keymap".

Comment: I chose XWin keymap in IDEA and also in MAC PC System Settings I remapped control key on fn. Hope it will help.